# Save CSV file in user's computer specific folder

Tags: php, csv, download

I have php script which download csv in download folder.

Can I force download in specific folder.?

I have PHP application which will be used by only one user also in one computer only.

If I can't then Is there any other solution .? Like allow user to save file in specif folder etc etc..?

Thank You

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .=''.$row["$i"].',';
}
$output .="\n";
}

$filename = "emp.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

Comment: Could you specify what you are using to download the content? e.g. `file_get_contents` or a CURL request etc.

Comment: no. server-side PHP code cannot do ANYTHING about telling the user where to save the file. that's a major security risk and not permitted. if you're talking about downloading this file to your SERVER, then that's your code and you can put the file anywhere you want.

Comment: No can do.... it's up to the client user to specify where a file should be downloaded, not the server application.... else malicious server code could overwrite system files with garbage, etc

Comment: Though most browsers do allow the user to specify a default download folder

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, noooooooooooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: Oh perfect..!! As I have one user using that application so i will change browser download folder.

Comment: Everybody is saying no to you but perhaps It's because you didn't ask the right question. Do you want to transfer a file between two computers of your own? If so, if they are linux based, you could use the bash command scp to copy a file between computers. If you want to do it well, you'll have to authorize automatic connections ssh

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, php is server side the client would have to decide where to store the file from download as the browser doesn't interact with the client's computer and only displays what server-side tells it to it cannot interact with the clients computer this will only interact with the browser.

so the answer in no unfortunately.